# Use [slug] as index also in Next

Tags: next.js

I'm exploring Next with an project, and I'm trying to handle all the routes with one file only. In this case: `[slug].tsx` so that means me to remove the `index.tsx`, I tried and didn't work, what do you think can be the way to achieve that.

[image]

Comment: So with my logic, it should work because even the `site.com` has the default `/` that should load it, but it doesn't, weird isn't it?

Comment: I guess the `slug` route will only intercepts when there is a slug in the route. When you omit the index file, and navigate to the root (without slug), next doesn't know how the handle it. But what you can try is to create the `index.tsx` file as a (hard) `symbolic` link pointing to the `[slug].tsx`. You would still see 2 files, but both pointing to the same file. I'm not sure if vscode and next will be able the handle this symlink.

Comment: You could look into [Optional Catch-all Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already mentioned, you can use an optional catch-all route.

So, rename your `[slug].tsx` as `[[...slug]].tsx`, so it will catch also the root without a slug.

Then delete your `.index.tsx` file.

Comment: So now I can't import: `Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).`

Comment: Yes, that's just how it is. Easiest to move your css import to app level

Comment: How do you deal with this in `getStaticPaths`?